# How can I use awk or grep to capture an entire Python traceback in a log file?

Tags: python, logging, awk, grep

A log file contains a number of Python tracebacks. I only care about tracebacks raised because of a `KevinCustomError`. There may be more than one of this class of error in the file.

How can I use `grep`, another popular unix command, or a combination thereof to dump the entire traceback for my specific error?

Here's an example log file. I would like lines 1-3 from this file. In the real log file the tracebacks are much longer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
KevinCustomError: integer division or modulo by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: I'd recommend `awk` instead. It works much better at handling this type of thing because you can store state (using variables) across multiple lines when you're processing your data.

Comment: I presume that the actual tracebacks aren't all just 3 lines long, right? As in, they're variable length.

Comment: voithos, that's correct

Comment: Are these standard prints outputting the exeption or are you using python logging?

Comment: We're calling logging.exception

Comment: @KevinBurke, maybe a slightly bigger example to show some other variation would be good. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59995991/5825294) I assume that both "tokens" `Traceback` and `KevinCustomError` are at the beginning of the respective lines, but I'm not sure this is true in general.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an AWK script I tried whipping together.

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}; /KevinCustomError/ {for(i=0; a[NR-i] !~ /Traceback/; i++) {} i++; while(i-- >= 0) {print a[NR-i]}}' logfile
```

Or, in file form.

```
{a[NR] = $0};

{
    if ($0 ~ /KevinCustomError/)
    {
        for (i = 0; a[NR-i] !~ /Traceback/; i++)
        {}
        i++
        while (i-- >= 0)
        {
            print a[NR-i];
        }
    }
}
```

Used like: `awk -f logscript.awk logfile`.

Not too familiar with AWK, so any criticism is welcome. Basically, it keeps track of all lines read so far, and just searches backwards to find a "Traceback" token (which you can replace if you'd like), and then prints everything in between (in the correct order).

Comment: I have not checked, nor I'm sure I've understood the general structure of the log, but I suspect the `for` could start at `i = 1` unless `KevinCustomError` can be on the same line as the preceding `Traceback`.

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood the structure of the Python log file, the following is a tiny `sed` solution, which is less cryptic than it seems

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
/^Traceback/{
:here
N
/\nKevinCustomError/b
s/.*\n\(Traceback\)/\1/
b here
}
```

**In summary**, the script takes action only on lines starting by `Traceback`; on these lines, the script keeps appending a new line (`N`) and subsequently checking if the newly added line starts by `KevinCustomError`; if this is the case, the script branches to the end and prints the multiline pattern space; if not, the script removes everything but the last `Traceback`-starting line from the pattern space, and then branches back to `:here` and appends another line (`N`), and so on.

In detail, it works as follows:

1. `#!/usr/bin/sed -f`: this is the [*shebang*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14887/164309) line, which tells the shell to use `/usr/bin/sed` as the interpreter, and to pass the file argument to it through the `-f` option (this allows executing `./script file` instead of `sed -f script file`);
2. `/^Traceback/` only matches the lines that start by `Traceback`;
3. `{…}` groups the commands that are executed only for those lines matched at step 2;

   1. `:here` is not a command, but just a label which marks the line where we can come back to by means of a `t`est or `b`ranch command;
   2. `N` reads and appends the following line of text the current pattern space inserting a newline `\n` in between, which makes the pattern space a multiline;
   3. `/\nKevinCustomError/b`, this `b`ranches to the end of the script if the pattern space contains `KevinCustomError` preceded by a `\n`;

      - **This results in `p`rinting the multiline pattern space**, which starts by `Traceback`, contains (at least) a `\n` in it, and contains `KevinCustomError` just after the (last) `\n`;
   4. `s/.*\n\(Traceback\)/\1/` (we are here if the pattern in 3. did not match) deletes the leading part of the patterns space up to and including the last `\n`;
   5. `b here` branches to `:here`, and no printing occurs at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this before for a similar issue. As a bonus, if you have multiple occurrences of KevinCustomError it will extract the traceback for each one.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$1
TOP='Traceback'
BOTTOM='KevinCustomError'

grep -n "$BOTTOM" $INPUT | while read match
do
    # This gets just the line number from the grep command
    END=${match%%:*}
    # Gets just the part of the file before END, flips it,
    # then gets the line number for TOP
    TEMP=`head -n $END $INPUT | tac | grep -n $TOP`
    # TEMP is really the number of lines from END to Traceback
    START=`expr $END - ${TEMP%%:*} + 1`
    echo $START $END
    sed -n "$START, $END p" < $INPUT
done
```

Output when run on your test data with the tracebacks flipped (because it is more interesting):

```
4 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
KevinCustomError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with `awk`:

```
awk '
/^KevinCustomError/ { for(;x<length(arry);) print arry[++x]; print $0 } 
/^Traceback/        { delete arry; i=x=0 }
                    { arry[++i]=$0 }
' logFile
```